# social network share links not working on desktop (fb://... whatsapp://...)

Tags: html, mobile, share, social-networking

When I use this kind of links

```
fb://sharer.php?u=...
whatsapp://send/?text=...
```

They work perfect on mobile devices, because the related application is opening (facebook or whatsapp) and ready to share the URL.

But when the links are clicked from a desktop computer, as the applications don't exist there, they are failing and returning an error page.

I would like to solve it using an elegant solution, for example, changing the links:

```
fb://sharer.php?u=...
```

Into:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php...
```

Which should work in desktop computers...
But to do that I would need a good way to determine which kind of device is visiting my website.

Is there a popular/working way to determine the visitor device? How would you fix it?

Comment: You can use Apple Universal Links & Android App Links.

Comment: I've had a look but this seems to be used to create links to specific places in a suposed app. But this is not my case. I don't have any app, i just want to add links to share my web content. At this moment i've found the solution for whatsapp, just using the next url `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=...` It checks if the app exists, and if not it redirects you to the whatsapp web site. I want to find the same "working" url for facebook